# Node.js callback confusion - Third argument of MongoDB's findOne(): Why is this permitted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm confused about JavaScript callbacks. I don't understand their logic and why they work. The following code is correct, but how can it be?

```
app.get('db').collection("foo").findOne({
  bar: req.query.baz
}, {
  _id: 0
}, (err, doc) => {
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      status: 503,
      message: "DB fault"
    });
    return;
  }
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    qux: doc
  });
});
```

That's the definition of MongoDB's findOne():

> db.collection.findOne(query, projection)

But in the code above, more than two parameters are passed, so I would expect an error.

Comment: first, in JS it's no error if you pass a function more arguments than it needs. Usually they are just ignored. MongoDB used to use this third argument to pass a callback function to deal with the async results. I know they were starting to also implement Promises as an alternative when they started to get popular. I'd guess that they switched completely to Promises, and that the old callback syntax is now deprecated. But that's just a guess.

Comment: This logic seems to still be in place, although it is no longer documented. [check the source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L1396). And what is it about callbacks, that confuses you?

Comment: Aaaah, I didn't know of the existence of the third parameter and I thought it's some special kind of JS or Node.js logic or something that even if a function has no callback function defined, it still can be used for a callback somehow.. But now I see, thanks! I'm still new to async programming and Node and this made me confused.

Comment: This pattern: a callback function as the last argument, with the `(error, data)` function args is quite common in nodejs. But Promises do take over. Especially since the introduction of [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) into the language. Wich are pretty much just syntactic sugar on top of promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That's the definition of MongoDB's findOne():
>
> > db.collection.findOne(query, projection)

No, that's the documentation -
 and probably from [the one for the shell commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/). If you look in the [API reference of the Node.js driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne) that you're actually using, you will find the callback parameter documented.

Answer (score 1):

Extra argument will never throw an error in JavaScript. Also in languages like C they will only at best create compile time errors. This is perfectly natural behaviour and you were using the wrong documentation. The correct one is, [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne)

```
findOne(query, options, callback) -> {Promise}
```

Since the API is supports Promises, you can actually omit the callback by chaining a then a use modern JavaScripts async / await

```
const value = await findOne(query, options)
```

There are many variances to that API. E.g. you could also asynchronously call an iterator of the Cursor like you would in Python. However the documented way is the oldest and likely also fastest way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on using Promises. I'll decide which format I prefer more.